# Backfill DataFrame Index by Minute?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a one column dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Close
0   100.000000
1   100.041108
2   100.852537
3   100.618285
4   100.191095
... ...
386 72.335508
387 72.978057
388 73.162437
389 73.407707
390 73.780661

391 rows × 1 columns
```

I'd like to re-index this dataframe, where the last row's index is not 390, but today's current date, at 16:00 for a time (as a datetime object), so it should look like this:

```
                    Close
0                   100.000000
1                   100.041108
2                   100.852537
3                   100.618285
4                   100.191095
...                 ...
386                 72.335508
387                 72.978057
388                 73.162437
389                 73.407707
2021-06-23 16:00    73.780661

391 rows × 1 columns
```

Then finally, I want to backfill the other indexes such that the current index is 1 minute less than the one below it, so the bottom section would look like this, but extrapolated all the way to the top of the df:

```
...                 ...
2021-06-23 15:56    72.335508
2021-06-23 15:57    72.978057
2021-06-23 15:58    73.162437
2021-06-23 15:59    73.407707
2021-06-23 16:00    73.780661

391 rows × 1 columns
```

How can this be done? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the slick answers, I was about to use a backwards for loop :P here's what I made for an answer:

```
    todays_datetime = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " 16:00"
    todays_datetime  = datetime.strptime(todays_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    idx = pd.date_range(end=todays_datetime, freq='min', periods=len(ind_df.index))
    ind_df = ind_df.set_index(idx)
```

Comment: FWIW, an alternative to `todays_datetime` is with a `replace` in between:  `pd.Timestamp("today").replace(hour=16, minute=0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Here's an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame, change with yours
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
end_dt = datetime(2021, 6, 23, 16, 0, 0)  # Change this if needed
idx = pd.date_range(end=end_dt, freq='min', periods=len(df.index))
df = df.set_index(idx)
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked like a charm, I'll post an update with the answer. I mod'd yours to use today's date so it's dynamic to whenever the script is run.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime('2021-06-23 16:00') 
              - pd.to_timedelta(df.index.max() - df.index,unit='m')
Out[191]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-23 15:56:00', '2021-06-23 15:57:00',
               '2021-06-23 15:58:00', '2021-06-23 15:59:00',
               '2021-06-23 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```